# Find value in the dictionary that matches the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to set a value from the dict if the condition is met. Basically I iterate over the values of my dictionary and check if they fit my condition (then I break to loop which is not the best practice but saves some iterations)

Here is the code I am using:

```
for (key,value) in zip(mn_zone_dict.keys(), mn_zone_dict.values()):
    if cost < value:
        zone = key
        break
```

I does it's job but it is relatively slow while I have to check > 10k records so I am looking for some smarter (and maybe more pythonic) way of solving that task. I have seen a function any() but it only returns if there is such entry which matches the conditions without telling which.

I'd be happy to hear your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide some example data for benchmarking? [For example, you can use `random` for a sample of X integers.] 10k records is very small, so a single query should be very fast. Are you willing to transform your data structure (e.g. `heapq`, `numpy`)?

Comment: What makes you think breaking out of a loop is not best practice, out of curiosity?

Comment: Back at the university I was told that it makes program unclear and it it better to handle a situation like that with some flag or anyhow but not with 'break'.

Comment: There is a Python construct, the loop `else`, built exactly around the advisability of using `break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the data directly as-is, with only a dictionary structure, you will have to iterate over it every time. The best speedup you can get would be to use a comprehension instead of a loop, and `dict.items` instead of `zip`:

```
zones = [k for k, v in my_zone_dict.items() if cost < v]
```

On the one hand this iterates over the whole dict. On the other, it tells you immediately how many values met the criterion, if any.

The problem here is that no matter how much less overhead a comprehension has than an explicit loop, this is still `O(n)` for every lookup. The correct solution is to use a different, or complimentary data structure. Since you want `value` to be greater than something, I'd recommend a max-heap.

Python implements heaps in the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module. It is a bit unusual because it does not provide a heap object, just functions to heapify and maintain lists as heaps. Also, only min-heaps are supported, but that's OK because you can always just negate your values:

```
my_zone_list = [(-v, k) for k, v in my_zone_dict.items()]
heapq.heapify(my_zone_list)
```

This is a one-time `O(n)` penalty, which you never have to repeat. Your whole loop now becomes an `O(1)` operation:

```
if cost < -my_zone_list[0][0]:
    zone = my_zone_list[0][1]
```

Inserting new elements has an `O(log(n))` cost:

```
heapq.heappush(my_zone_list, (-new_value, new_key))
```

As a side note, if you can't introduce new data structures, you *might* get better performance with

```
v, zone = max((v, k) for k, v in my_zone_dict.items())
if cost < v: ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of iterating a `zip` object, you can iterate directly over `dict.items`:

```
for k, v in my_zon_dict.items():
    if cost < v:
        zone = k
        break
```

This will be more efficient than creating a custom zipped iterable.

Comment: I would like to skip the part of iterating over the dict but still thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @hikamare It is *impossible* to avoid iterating, this *is* the pythonic way, or if you want a one-liner, you could do `zone = next(k for k, v in my_zon_dict.items() if cost < v)`

Comment: @hikamare, I second Chris_Rands, what you asking for is impossible.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, In my experience generator expression iteration is *slower*, so not sure the one-liner is useful here!

Comment: I doubt the speed will be meaninfully different but when they say "I have seen a function any() but it only returns if there is such entry which matches the conditions without telling which." it sounds like they are looking for `next()`. Nonetheless your solution is fine, I hope you don't mind my edit, and not my vote of course

Comment: I think the solution is to completely change the approach rather than squeeze cycles out of the same one. You can do the lookup on a heap without looping at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
for k in my_zon_dict.keys():
   if cost < my_zon_dict[k]:
      zone = k
      break
```